# php insert date of birth into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I am using html `<select>`, `<option>`  form to collect data from users. However, I got stuck when trying to save the day of birth to the database.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$dob = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' .$_POST['day'];

$insertInto = " INSERT INTO `users`.`information` (id, useremail, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dob, telephone)
VALUES ( NULL, '$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[formGender]','$dob', '$_POST[telephone]')";
```

It works for everything but the `$dob`, could someone guide me on finding the error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should NEVER pass user strings directly to PHP. What if the user enters an e-mail like `NULL); DROP TABLE users; --`? Always escape user input with mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I will check with ISSET and then for validation, I am just not at that point yet. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: That's not really a realistic vector ChrisJ, who I happen to share first name/last initial with. I would instead do something like: `email=',firstname=SELECT password FROM users.information WHERE useremail='target@email.com','','','','')`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using unix's epoch, you can simply take your users input and do a simple strtotime(). It'll give you more flexibility on pulling it out and how you can display it using the date() function.

```
$dob = "1/1/1985";
$string = strtotime($dob);
```

then to spit it out:

```
$data = pull epoch result from database
$birthday = date("m/d/Y", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the value of $dob before doing the query call. Then, if it looks alright (1984-10-10 for example), make your dob is a date/datetime.

By now, what error are you getting? Is it being set to all 0's or what exactly?

Note: you will be exposed to SQL injection. I would always recommend using PDO with prepared statements for nearly any SQL query. http://mx.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: i am getting 0000-00-00.  i tried to echo my $dob varialbe its echo right but when i see in phpmyadmin there is 0000-00-00. In echo i get 1997-06-12